# Making deterministic versions of a parametrized question

Tags: r-exams

Suppose that a question is parametrized on parameters `a` and `b`. And suppose that `a` can take the values 1, 2 and 3, and that `b` can take the values 1 and 2. Is it possible to get a version for each combination of the possible values of `a` and `b`? That is:

```
a = 1, b = 1;

a = 2, b = 1;

a = 3, b = 1;

a = 1, b = 2;

...
```

I mean all values for `a` and `b` would have to be deterministically generated and not randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can easily generate the six fixed versions by using `expar("myfile.Rmd", a = 1, b = 1)` etc. Some more details from `?expar` are provided below.

**Note:** However, the main motivation for that function is not to generate *all* versions of an exercise (although it can be used for this) but to fix some parameters in an exercise, e.g., to assure that the random variation between participants does not become too large. At least that's what I use it for. I don't mind about exactly generating all versions

**Details:** The `expar()` function copies an exercise file (in a temporary directory) and replaces the first assignment to the specified parameter in the first code chunk. It returns the path to the temporary file with the modified exercise. This can then be processed with 'exams2xyz' "as usual". From `?expar`:

> To work properly, the parameter of interest must be defined with a
> standard assignment in the first code chunk at the beginning of a
> line.  The original definition of the parameter must be in a
> single line only (typically using something like `sample` or
> `runif` etc.).

**Example:** Based on the [deriv](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/deriv/) exercise.

```
myderiv <- expar("deriv.Rmd", a = 1, b = 2)
myderiv
## [1] "/tmp/RtmpEnHBap/deriv+606EE82A+D5F7B.Rmd"
exams2html(myderiv)
```

**Iteration:**
If you want to iterate over all possible combinations of several parameters in your exercise, you can use `expand.grid()` and `sapply()`. A small convenience function for this could be:

```
expargrid <- function(file, ...) {
  df <- expand.grid(...)
  stopifnot(nrow(df) >= 1L)
  sapply(1L:nrow(df), function(i) {
    args <- as.list(df[i,])
    args <- c(list(file = file), args)
    do.call(exams::expar, args)
  })
}
```

And then you can iterate for example:

```
myderivs <- expargrid("deriv.Rmd", a = 1:3, b = 1:2)
myderivs
## [1] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8A2C4.Rmd"
## [2] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8A838.Rmd"
## [3] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8AD47.Rmd"
## [4] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8B238.Rmd"
## [5] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8B71D.Rmd"
## [6] "/tmp/RtmpfB5SQB/deriv+606F0DA0+8BC06.Rmd"
exams2html(myderivs)
```

Comment: Thanks, Achim! I think it would help to have `expar` to accept vectors for the parameters to be fixed. In the context of my example: `a=1:3` and `b=1:2`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit concerned that this would open more questions than it answers. (a) You might really want to set `a` to a vector of values `1:3` within a single exercise. (b) With `a = 1:3` and `b = 1:3` one might expect three exercises with pairs of parameters rather than nine factorial combinations. (c) Users will have different expectations about whether the order is cycling through `a` first or through `b` first. So I would rather encourage you to write a function, say, `expargrid()` that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I've added a possible implementation of `expargrid()` to my answer.

Comment: Perfect, Achim! Thanks! However, if there were a logical parameter `fullgrid` in function `exam2xyz()`, the ambiguity would disappear. But I understand that it may be not worthy the effort, since a function like yours `expargrid()` does what is wanted.