# How to include all elements of a vector in an exams2moodle or exams2pdf output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-exams

I am working on a simple code to find the square root of the following elements:

```
   dat <- c(4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225)
   num<-sample(dat ,1,replace=F)
```

Parts of the seed file are configured like this:

```
 examen01<-c("SinRad.Rmd")
   semilla<-sample(100:1000, 1)
   set.seed(semilla) 

   exams2moodle(examen01,n=14,svg=TRUE,name="SinRadConRad",
              encoding="UTF-8",dir="salida",edir="ejercicios",
              mchoice = list(shuffle = TRUE,answernumbering = "ABCD",
              solution = FALSE,
              eval = list(partial = TRUE,rule = "none")))
```

I intend that, with n=14, all the responses to the options found in the "dat" vector are included, but I see that there are responses that are repeated.

How to achieve 14 answers for the 14 possibilities, without repeating or missing any?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you should generate 14 files to use every case exactly once. IMHO there isn't easy solution but I interest the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exams2xyz()` functions have been written to draw large numbers of random variations from sets of exercises. There is no dedicated functionality that draws a small number of deterministic variations. So in your case I would just draw, say, a hundred variations from the exercise template even if it can only yield 14 distinct versions. Sure, this wastes a bit of memory but not so much that I would worry about this.

Having said that, it is possible to set up a temporary file with a specific version of an exercise by using the `expar()` function. For example, `expar("SinRad.Rmd", num = 4)` would yield an exercise where the `num` parameter has been fixed to `4`. Then in the same way you can cycle through the other 13 numbers you want. In the following post we also provide an `expargrid()` function that does this for all possible combinationso of parameters: [Making deterministic versions of a parametrized question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002511/making-deterministic-versions-of-a-parametrized-question/67003267#67003267)

Then you can run `exams2moodle()` on the resulting 14 deterministic exercise files.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!